# Rspec tests hanging with Paperclip

Tags: ruby-on-rails, unit-testing, rspec, paperclip

I have a Picture model in my app that uses Paperclip to attach an image to it.

The model:

```
class Picture < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_attached_file :image, :default_url => "/system/:attachment/missing.png", :styles => { :small => "100x100#", :medium => "460x460>", :large => "1024x1024>" }

  validates_attachment_presence :image
  validates_attachment_content_type :image, :content_type => [/image\/(x-)?png/i, /image\/(p)?jpeg/i]
  validates_attachment_size :image, :less_than => 5.megabytes

  validates_presence_of :name
  validates_format_of :name, :with => /^[a-z0-9_\-!@#%&()' ]+$/i
end
```

When I run my tests they hang at this part of the test in the log:

```
Processing PagesController#index (for 0.0.0.0 at 2010-07-10 11:29:54) [GET]
  Parameters: {"action"=>"index", "controller"=>"pages"}
  Picture Load (0.2ms)   SELECT * FROM "pictures" LIMIT 1
Rendering template within layouts/application
Rendering pages/index
Completed in 2ms (View: 0, DB: 0) | 200 OK [http://test.host/index]
[paperclip] identify '-format' '%wx%h' '/var/folders/cD/cDCiDnTlH5ehwTjJq1pxYE+++TI/-Tmp-/stream,6515,0.txt[0]' 2>/dev/null
```

My Pages controller looks like this:

```
class PagesController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @picture = Picture.first ? Picture.first : Picture.new
  end
end
```

The test for the controller looks like this:

```
describe PagesController do
  describe "GET 'index'" do
    before(:each) do
      get :index
    end

    it "should be successful" do
      response.should be_success
    end

    it "should assign picture" do
      assigns[:picture].should_not be_nil
    end

    it "should assign a valid picture" do
      assigns[:picture].class.should == Picture
    end
  end
end
```

My tests are also hanging when running `rake spec:models` it just shows the

```
[paperclip] identify '-format' '%wx%h' '/var/folders/cD/cDCiDnTlH5ehwTjJq1pxYE+++TI/-Tmp-/stream,6515,0.txt[0]' 2>/dev/null
```

line in the log. My model test looks like:

```
describe Picture do
  it { should have_attached_file(:image) }
  it { should validate_attachment_presence(:image) }
  it {
    should validate_attachment_content_type(:image).
    allowing('image/png', 'image/x-png', 'image/jpeg', 'image/pjpeg').
    rejecting('text/plain', 'text/xml', 'image/tiff')
  }
  it { should validate_attachment_size(:image).less_than(5.megabytes) }

  it { should validate_presence_of(:name) }
  ["Client's website", "This is a great site!", "my_awes0me-s!te"].each do |phrase|
    it { should allow_value(phrase).for(:name) }
  end
  ["Client's web$ite", "This is a great^ site!", "my_awes;0me-s!te"].each do |phrase|
    it { should_not allow_value(phrase).for(:name) }
  end

  context "is new" do
    it "should have a default missing image" do
      picture = Picture.new
      picture.image.url.should == "/system/images/missing.png"
    end
  end
end
```

Why is this freezing? (If I run the model tests for a while it does move slowly, looks like it is running all the conversions, how can I stub these out?)

Answer (score 1):

I have the same issue with ruby 1.8.7 - but no hanging at all on ruby 1.9.2

This [link](https://github.com/mudge/paperclip/commit/d3dd2fa566241d6ce37ba993a871e08bf83b21f5) solves the issue for me.